# How to fix /Library/ conflicts in GitHub repo for Unity project?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, gitignore

We got it so that the Unity Project folder doubles as our git repo. We made the git repo and forgot to get the .gitignore file in there. Now /library/ conflicts are preventing anyone from working with the repo, even after we created the .gitignore file in the master. We aren't sure how to fix this without losing a lot of work and starting over in GitHub.

Our repo is at the following link: https://github.com/warpaltarpers/IMS487

Please help us on this one, as we can't move forward without fixing this, and we would rather not delete the repo to start over with version control.

Comment: You need to delete those files from the repo (with `git rm`).

Comment: A couple of questions related to a few places the problem can be originating from: 1) The `.gitignore` was made; but did you delete `/library/` from the repo? 2) The remote repo has the `.gitignore` file, but local(s) don't? Or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to go through each branch and remove the library folder and add the .gitignore

Thank you for helping me out on this.